# Switch from one page to another in bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to create multi-page registration form using Bootstrap's modal. I am developing with ASP.NET MVC. Initial view is being loaded through a partial view, see code below.

```
<!-- Registration Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Registration/Index.cshtml")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It has a Next button. Is it possible to load the next page without having to close the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- Registration Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
<div id="divRegistration"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($('#divRegistration') != undefined) {
   $("#divRegistration").load("@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")");

}});
</script>
```